# 5d nonabelian gauge theory or 5d QCD explicit $\beta$-function

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, feynman-diagrams, quantum-chromodynamics, effective-field-theory

> Question: Are there some derived $\beta$-function formula
> $$
> \beta(g) = \frac{\partial g}{\partial \log(\mu)}
> $$ for nonabelian gauge theory in the 5-dimensional spacetime at some energy scale $\mu$ and coupling $g$? Can you provide **the references, physical interpretations, and explicit formulas?**

Background, for the well-known 4d:

In 4d, for nonabelian Yang-Mills gauge theory with a gauge group $G=SU(N_c)$, with Dirac fermions in a representations of Lie groups $R_f$ of$G$ and with complex scalars in a representation $R_s$, the one-loop beta function is
$$
\beta(g)=-\left(\frac{11}{3}C_2(G)-\frac{1}{3}n_sT(R_s)-\frac{4}{3}n_f T(R_f)\right)\frac{g^3}{16\pi^2}~,
$$
where $C_2(G)$ is the quadratic Casimir of $G$ and $T(R)$ is another Casimir invariant defined by $Tr (T^a_RT^b_R) = T(R)\delta^{ab}$ for generators $T^{a,b}_R$ of the Lie algebra in the representation R.

For Weyl fermions, replace 4/3 by 2/3, and for real scalars, replace 1/3 by 1/6.

For gauge fields (gluons), necessarily in the adjoint of $G$, $C_2(G) = N_c$; for fermions in the fundamental representation (or anti-fundamental) representation of $G$, $T(R) = 1/2$. Then for QCD, with $N_c = 3$, the above equation reduces to that for the quantum chromodynamics beta function:
$$
\beta(\alpha_s)=-\left(11- \frac{n_s}{6}-\frac{2n_f}{3}\right)\frac{\alpha_s^2}{2\pi}
$$

> How about the 5d $\beta$-function?

Comment: Non-renormalizable, right? Write down the dimension of *g* . What are  you going to do?

Comment: Thanks. We can still ask about the high energy and the low energy behaviors of 5d theory? (strong vs weak coupling)

Comment: Mostly I care about the low energy / IR behavior.

Comment: [Oh](https://arxiv.org/abs/0911.3609).

Comment: thanks so much for the ref!